# Kafka Streams: pipe one topic into another

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm new to Kafka Streams and I'm using it to make an exact copy of a topic into another with a different name. This topic has several partitions and my producers are using custom partitioners. The output topic is created beforehand with the same number of partitions of the input topic.

In my app, I did (I'm using Kotlin):

```
val builder = StreamsBuilder()
builder
    .stream<Any, Any>(inputTopic)
    .to(outputTopic)
```

This works, except for the partitions (because of course I'm using a custom partitioner). Is there a simple way to copy input records to the output topic using the same partition of the input record?

I checked the Processor API that allows to access the partition of the input record through a `ProcessorContext` but I was unable to manually set the partition of the output record.

Apparently, I could use a custom partitioner in the sink, but that would imply deserializing and serializing the records to recalculate the output partition with my custom partitioner.

Comment: Why do you want to copy a topic? The use case is unclear to me.

Comment: It's just one step of a migration procedure. I ended up using standard `KafkaProducer` and `KafkaConsumer`.

Answer (score 2):

`Produced` (that is one of the `KStream::to` arguments) has `StreamPartitioner` as one of its member.

You could try following code:

```java
builder.stream("input", Consumed.with(Serdes.ByteArray(), Serdes.ByteArray()))
  .to("output", Produced.with(Serdes.ByteArray(), Serdes.ByteArray(), (topicName, key, value, numberOfPartitions) -> calculatePartition(topicName, key, value, numberOfPartitions));
```

In above code only `ByteArray` `Serdes` are used so any special serialization or deserialization happens.

Comment: So far, this looks like the cleanest way. However, it would still imply deserializing and serializing the record as my custom partitioner uses data from the record to calculate the partition (which I'd like to avoid, as stated in my question). I ended up rewriting the code using standard `KafkaConsumer` and `KafkaProducer` which allow me to do exactly what I want without deserialization.

Comment: You could use `builder.stream().transform().to()` and put the partition from the `context` into a member variable of the `StreamPartitioner` (ie, you also need to give a reference of the `StreamPartitioner` instance into the `Transformer`).

Comment: I thought MirrorMaker already solves this issue. Can someone please point me out potential issues with MirrorMaker?

Comment: Can mirror make copy a topic with the same cluster? From my understanding, it's for cross-cluster replication.

Answer (score -2):

Firstly, messages are distributed among partitions based on Key. A message with similar key would always go in the same partition.

So if your messages have keys then you don't need to worry about it at all. As long as you have similar number of partitions as your original topic; it would be taken care of.

Secondly, if you are copying data to another topic as it is then you should consider using the original topic instead. Kafka has notion of consumer-groups.

For example, you have a topic 'transactions' then you can have consumer-groups i.e. 'credit card processor', 'mortgage payment processor', 'apple pay processor' and so on. Consumer-groups would read the same topic and filter out events that are meaningful to them and process them.

You can also create 3 topics and achieve the same result. Though, it's not an optimal solution. You can find more information at https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/.

[image]

Comment: Firstly, in Kafka messages are distributed among partitions by the client based on a Partitioner. The *default* partitioner calculates the partition as `partition = hash(key) % nr_partitions`. My partitioner does something different (due to app logic reasons).

Secondly, I'm copying topics as a one off operation as part of a larger migration plan to event sourcing.

Comment: I guess you can take advantage of mirroring using Apache MirrorMaker. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=27846330  https://docs.confluent.io/current/multi-dc-replicator/mirrormaker.html

Comment: It has the same problem. MirrorMaker uses an embedded producer and as such, of course it will have to calculate a partition for the output record. And it will obviously use the default partitioner which in my case is wrong.

Comment: Have you tried mirror-maker? I believe as long as you have provided appropriate keys to your messages; your messages would be distributed among partitions in the same way they were partitioned in the original topic. If that does not happen then whole point of mirroring would be defeated. https://grokbase.com/t/kafka/users/14btx8ygd9/can-mirroring-preserve-every-topics-partition

Comment: In that thread they mention tweaking the MM code. In that case, it's just way easier to do it with standard `KafkaProducer` and `KafkaConsumer`.

Comment: Messages are stored in (Key, Value) pair. MirrorMaker's producer might send your message with the exact same (Key, Value) pair. If you want to write your own producer then that's fine but MM would be doing it for you already.

Comment: I don't think you've understood my first comment. A (Key, Value) pair determines the partition only if you're using Kafka's `DefaultPartitioner`. https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/internals/DefaultPartitioner.java . I am NOT using the default partitioner.

Comment: If messages with Key-A of partition-0 of source Kafka cluster ends up in partition-10 of destination Kafka cluster; what wrong can happen? If your custom partitioner distributes messages with Key-A on different partitions then your custom partitioner needs an update big-time.